# Example of a relation (in math sense/relational algebra) illustrated on SQL table

Tags: sql, database, relation

I have a table with header "ID" (Integer), "Name" (String), "Address" (String).

```
+---------------------+
|  ID | Name  | City  |
+---------------------+
| 1  | John  | London |
| 2  | Mary  | Paris  |
| 3  | Cris  | Tokio  |
+---------------------+
```

Could you please help me and show how that table is a relation?

Binary Relation is a set of ordered pairs, each pair is a mapping from set A to set B
(like A={1,2,3} B={A,B} => {1A, 2A, 2B, 3A} is a binary relation)

I guess table header (set of attribute names) form the first set of pair (A as in example above), but what is the second set in my case? And what is a 3-tuple ("1  | John  | London") if I need to have pairs (and tuple is not a pair) - the second part of that pair (A set) is just always implicitly implied?

I think in my case it is a ternary relation, I have three sets (set of ISs, set of Names, set of cities) and table header shall not be considered a set speaking about relations (header is used because all 3-tuples would be ordered according to header). So *binary relation is totally unrelated to my table.* Am I right?

[prooflink](https://www.cs.odu.edu/~cs381/cs381content/relation/definition/cp_gen/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Don't mix binary relation in mathematics with Binary Relation in Database. In DB concept binary relation points the relationship between two different Entities where as binary relation in math is related to Set Theory. [See this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/208913/binary-relations-set-theory)

Altough they are different there are close relationships between them. You can check *Applied Mathematics for Database Professionals*

Answer (score 0):

1) **For table header:**

relation is a **set** of (ordered) *pairs*:

```
{ (ID, Integer), {Name, String}, {City, String) }
```

2) **For table body**

relation is a **set** of (ordered) *pairs*:

```
{ (ID, 1), (Name, John), (City, London),  
  (ID, 2), (Name, Mary), (City, Paris), 
  (ID, 3), (Name, Cris), (City, Tokio) }
```

For example these three pairs `{ (ID, 1), (Name, John), (City, London) }` mean a *tuple (3-tuple = record = table row)*. More exactly a tuple shall be a set of (ordered) triples, not set of pairs: `{ (ID, Integer, 1), (Name, String, John), (City, String, London) }`, but whenever we see *"ID"* we always know it is *Integer* (domain = data type), so domain/type is omitted and so we speak of pairs (instead of speaking about triplets).

So a (normalized) table can be analagous to an algebraic binary relation and binary relation is defined as a set of ordered pairs.

I am just not 100% sure if for such relaltion=table the set of pairs for the relation shall include union of pair sets in 1 and 2 (sets of pirs for header and body).